# Migrating Server 2003 -> Server 2008 r2. Global Catalog location. DNS problems

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, domain-controller

I've got a dying server with a WinServer 2003 installed. It's a Domain Controller. I've made a virtual machine with a Server 2008 r2 and migrated all roles on it. But there is a problem. Global Catalog is still located on the old server despite the new one has a Global Catalog option turned on. It says:

```
Log Name:      Directory Service
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-ActiveDirectory_DomainService
Date:          30.08.2013 18:45:20
Event ID:      1869
Task Category: Global Catalog
Level:         Information
Keywords:      Classic
User:          ANONYMOUS LOGON
Computer:      vm-dns2.logstream.local
Description:
Active Directory Domain Services has located a global catalog in the following site. 

Global catalog:
\\server.logstream.local 
Site:
Default-First-Site-Name
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-ActiveDirectory_DomainService" Guid="{0e8478c5-3605-4e8c-8497-1e730c959516}" EventSourceName="NTDS General" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="16384">1869</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>4</Level>
    <Task>18</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-08-30T14:45:20.007237900Z" />
    <EventRecordID>186</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="484" ThreadID="604" />
    <Channel>Directory Service</Channel>
    <Computer>vm-dns2.logstream.local</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-7" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>\\server.logstream.local</Data>
    <Data>Default-First-Site-Name</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

I need GC to be located on the new server to let the old one eventually die. Could someone please help me with that?

I agree there may be some DNS problems. If the old DC is off, the new one sais:

```
Log Name:      Directory Service
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-ActiveDirectory_DomainService
Date:          02.09.2013 12:58:06
Event ID:      1126
Task Category: Global Catalog
Level:         Error
Keywords:      Classic
User:          ANONYMOUS LOGON
Computer:      vm-dns2.logstream.local
Description:
Active Directory Domain Services was unable to establish a connection with the global catalog. 

Additional Data 
Error value:
1355 The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted. 
Internal ID:
3200e25 

User Action: 
Make sure a global catalog is available in the forest, and is reachable from this domain controller. You may use the nltest utility to diagnose this problem.
Event Xml:
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-ActiveDirectory_DomainService" Guid="{0e8478c5-3605-4e8c-8497-1e730c959516}" EventSourceName="NTDS General" />
    <EventID Qualifiers="49152">1126</EventID>
    <Version>0</Version>
    <Level>2</Level>
    <Task>18</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8080000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2013-09-02T08:58:06.650172500Z" />
    <EventRecordID>248</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation />
    <Execution ProcessID="484" ThreadID="604" />
    <Channel>Directory Service</Channel>
    <Computer>vm-dns2.logstream.local</Computer>
    <Security UserID="S-1-5-7" />
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data>3200e25</Data>
    <Data>1355</Data>
    <Data>The specified domain either does not exist or could not be contacted.</Data>
  </EventData>
</Event>
```

And just after that appears a 2092 event:

> This server is the owner of the following FSMO role, but does not
>   consider it valid. For the partition which contains the FSMO, this
>   server has not replicated successfully with any of its partners since
>   this server has been restarted. Replication errors are preventing
>   validation of this role.    Operations which require contacting a FSMO
>   operation master will fail until this condition is corrected.    FSMO
>   Role: DC=logstream,DC=local

The other machines with automatic net configuration say that DNS server is 192.168.0.1 which is a router

Answer (score 10):

It's OK... global catalog doesn't need to be "migrated" from one DC to another, per se.  Just make all your domain controllers GCs.  That's it.  There's no problem decommissioning a domain controller that is a GC. All your domain controllers should all be GCs at the same time.

Comment: They both are GCs at the time but when the old one is off the new one says that it can't contact to global catalog. That's why I want to make sure global catalog is physically located on the new DC

Comment: @Konstantin - You're misunderstanding the Global Catalog. From a command prompt run "nltest /dnsgetdc:yourdomain.tld /gc". If both DC's are returned in the results then the GC is fine on both servers.

Comment: My guess is that you have DNS misconfigured somewhere.

Comment: Right, so on your extant domain controller, make sure that its DNS resolvers are set to #1) Another DC in your domain that is *not* the one that you're trying to retire, and #2) 127.0.0.1.  Do not list 127.0.0.1 as the primary DNS resolver on your DC *unless* it is the *only* domain controller in the domain.

Comment: I've done what you've advised successfully but that didn't help. The old DC is also a WINS and DHCP server but we've got a router which also is a DHCP server besides it's a gateway. Maybe I should migrate DHCP and WINS too?

Comment: DHCP and WINS are optional components; they have nothing to do with the successful operation of AD. (You're not supposed to have two DHCP servers on the same network but that's an entirely separate issue.) #1 Did you transfer or seize the FSMO roles when you put them on the new DC, and #2) Did you let the initial replication finish during the promotion of the new DC before you shut the old one down?

Comment: Also, yes, you're going to keep getting errors from a missing DC until you demote it. AD still thinks it's supposed to be there, and will still bark at you when you power it off, until you demote it.

Comment: Thanks for advices! Yes, i've transfered the FSMO roles and seized them later to be sure they are assigned to the new DC. Replication also gone well. So should I demote the old DC from GC to just DC or maybe it can be just removed from computers and DC lists to stop torment with it?

Comment: Run DCPromo on it to gracefully demote the old DC.